# L' économie « circulaire » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, adjectifs, terminologie, économie

Sur [FranceTerme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/ENVI106?from=list&francetermeSearchTerme=%C3%A9conomie%20circulaire&francetermeSearchDomaine=0) on trouve une définition de 2015 pour l'*économie circulaire* :

> Organisation d’activités économiques et sociales recourant à des modes
>   de production, de consommation et d’échange fondés sur
>   l’écoconception, la réparation, le réemploi et le recyclage, et visant
>   à diminuer les ressources utilisées ainsi que les dommages causés à
>   l’environnement.

Sur [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89conomie_circulaire) on nous dit qu'il s'agit d'un concept économique qui :

> [...] s'inscrit dans le cadre du développement durable et qui
>   s'inspire notamment des notions d'économie verte, d’économie de
>   l'usage ou de l'économie de la fonctionnalité, de l'économie de la
>   performance et de l'écologie industrielle (laquelle veut que le déchet
>   d'une industrie soit recyclé en matière première d'une autre industrie
>   ou de la même).

Et qu'« une telle économie fonctionne en boucle, se passant ainsi de la notion de déchet » (Wikipédia). Ailleurs on a vu qu'une société visait un *système de production circulaire*.

- Sur quel sens de [circulaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/circulaire) s'appuie la notion d'*économie circulaire* et peut-il se greffer à un *système de
  production (circulaire)*, voire à une *chaîne de montage* : s'agit-il du cercle, de son mouvement, du retour au point de départ, du pourtour, du passage de
  main en main, tous à la fois ; pourquoi ne s'agit-il pas d'un système de production « [écologique](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8364374) »?
- Comment indique-t-on le plus ou moins haut degré d'atteinte de la « circularité » dans le sens en question (système... de production circulaire... ): est-ce avec l'adjectif *complet, élevé, étanche* etc. ?

Comment: Dans cette expression,  _circulaire_ évoque pour moi la notion de cycle, comme tous ceux qu'on trouve dans la nature: le cycle de l'eau ou du carbone, le cycle des saisons, etc.

Comment: @mouviciel N'hésitez pas à verser votre commentaire en réponse ! Merci !

Comment: Voilà qui est fait.

Answer (score 3):

Dans cette expression, *circulaire* évoque pour moi la notion de cycle, comme tous ceux qu'on trouve dans la nature: le cycle de l'eau ou du carbone, le cycle des saisons, etc. où chaque chose revient à sa position initiale après avoir traversé de multiples transformations.

Comment: Merci ! Et le haut degré de ce qui est cyclique, comment exprimerait-t-on ça quand on parle d'un système de production circulaire ?

Answer (score 1):

**A_** Parmi les sens désignés le seul qui convienne est le suivant;

A3.**Qui revient à son point de départ.
a) Voyage circulaire. Dont le parcours est plus ou moins en forme de cercle et ramène au point de départ.**

Si l'on considère les définitions relatives au cercle (1. et 2.) on trouve qu'elles s'appliquent à la signification la plus concrète du mot cercle, c'est à dire, à la figure géométrique; un sens figuré peut sans risque être écarté : « qui fait le tour d'un domaine, qui l'embrasse tout entier ». Il n'y aurait alors de concevable que l'interprétation de « groupes d'entités économiques chacun consacré à un domaine tout entier » et si on attachait quelque crédit à ce sens il semble qu'on en viendrait à parler d'économies de trusts, de trusts verticaux et horizontaux et d'autres modèles; l'aspect de l'économie qui nous concerne, quelle qu'en soit la facette exacte que l'on essaie de déterminer, n'a rien à voir avec la question de sa structuration administrative ou peu; l'aspect considéré est celui de ses responsabilités dans les domaines de l'environnement et de la meilleure utilisation des ressources. Autrement, « Toute l'économie faisant le tour d'un domaine tout entier » ne signifie rien.
Le sens au « B », « qui passe de main en main » de prime abord peut arrêter l'esprit puisqu'il est question de recyclage, et qu'un des principes du recyclage et de ne pas abandonner les résidus de production mais d'en faire la propriété d'un producteur à des fins utiles, donc disons de les « passer à un producteur », mais l'idée essentielle dans le mot « recyclage », qui contient encore, si sous une différente guise, le mot « cercle », c'est celle de retour à l'utilisation première ou à défaut à *une* utilisation première (la bouteille de verre vide est lavée puis remplie avec le même produit ou bien elle est fondue et sert à faire d'autres bouteilles, par exemple); il manque donc à ce sens une composante fondamentale. Le seule sens qui puisse être retenu semble donc être « A3 ». Évidemment on est amené à jouer un peu sur les mots, faire de « voyage » plutôt « parcours » ou quelque autre terme voisin plus approprié à la discussion concernant l'économie; on est aussi amené à considérer un cercle abstrait (ce qui ne fait pas partie de la définition du dictionnaire mais un usage analogique pas encore établi va de paire avec une certaine liberté de l'utiliser quand même). La remarque à propos de la particularisation du concept de circularité aux chaines de montages est totalement obscure : il est question dans l'essentiel de la demande d'explications de pratiques générales dans toute l'économie d'un pays ou de l'économie mondiale et les chaines de montages ne sont ni un rouage de l'économie ni un élément dans le processus de production auquel soit associé des questions sur le plan de l'écologie et du recyclage; un éclaircissement est nécessaire sur ce point.

« Pourquoi ne s'agit-il pas d'un système de production « écologique »? » est une question à se poser; le système se comprend d'emblée comme nécessairement  écologique, quel que soit l'importance que puisse avoir ce concept, et comme fondé en partie sur le recyclage. Il faut noter que dans la définition de France-Terme le mot recyclage ne prend pas sous sa coupe l'idée de réemploi puisque ce mot figure dans la même énumération. Ce concept est assimilable au concept de recyclage et il est de la catégorie des concepts caractérisés comme ayant la propriété de « ce qui revient à son point de départ ». On peut faire la même remarque pour « réparation » : une réparation ramène au point de départ (plus ou moins). Il y a à examiner maintenant le concept d'écoconception. Le principe que ce terme met en avant est celui de la préservation de l'environnement et évidemment l'idée qui pourrait être sous-entendue que de ne pas détériorer l'environnement, c'est à dire de laisser comme tel, est équivalente à celle de le détériorer puis de lui rendre sa nature première et ainsi de revenir au point de départ, cela dans le but de définir un retour au point de départ, une circularité dirons-nous enfin , ne peut pas plaire à beaucoup de monde et je n'y accorde que très peu de considération. Il faut apparemment conclure que, comme l'écoconception, ayant une part importante dans le fonctionnement de l'économie moderne, ne peut être ni négligée pour insignifiante dans la constitution d'un programme écologique, ni être assimilée à un principe de circularité, le terme « circulaire » par lequel elle est nécessairement caractérisée ne convient pas. Il s'agirait donc d'une économie écoconceptive et circulaire ou économie « écologique »; il faut cependant ne pas faire l'erreur d'établir la circularité comme un mécanisme à but purement  écologique.

**B_** Il est nécessaire selon la définition de considérer non seulement la production mais aussi la consommation; il est question dans la circularité, de réparation,  c'est à dire de la réparation des biens de consommation solides . Il semble apparent que le principe de circularité n'ayant pas encore été exploité de façons consistante ni de façon poussée, il n'y ait pas encore eu beaucoup de stimulation  a évaluer l'impact de sa mise en pratique, et donc il n'y a probablement pas encore un usage établi; une circularité du plus haut degré pourrait être appelée **maximale, totale, complète**; pour des degrés intermédiaires des adjectif comme **nulle, faible, forte, élevée** sont envisageables; des adjectif  plus ou moins passe-partout semblent acceptables.